# Understanding how scopes can be used for user authorization in Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth, active-directory, azure-active-directory, openid

When reading about Azure AD and OAuth authorization scopes always comes up. However I dont understand how they can be used in the to following scenario:

### What I have setup:

I have two applications registered, one is a SPA and the other is a WEB API. I use the implicit grant flow in the SPA to request an access token for the WEB API. In the WEB API app I have registered four scopes A, B, C and D.

### What the scenario is:

A user arrives to my SPA and is redirected to Azure AD. The client makes a request for an access token using the implicit flow. When setting up the client that makes the actual request to Azure AD the scopes (A, B, C and D) are provided.

### What I dont understand:

When the user arrives to the SPA the scopes are already hardcoded on the SPA client. What I want is for different human user to get access to different scopes on the WEB API.

### My Questions are:

- Are scopes only relevant when you have multiple client applications
  and not related to when you have multiple actual human user?
- If scopes are not applicable to user what alternatives are there?
- If scopes are applicable to users also how do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding , your questions are Azure AD V2 Microsoft Graph user scope related.And this is my answer below :

> 1. If you use a signed user to get access token(password flow), the scope (in other word, the permission of the access token)is all related with the user , we call permissions here as **Delegated permissions** . If you use a client application to get access token(client_credentials flow), the permission of access token is all related to client application, we call the permission here as **Application permissions** . 
>      If you want to know more about it , pls refer to [this official doc](http://Application%20permissions).
>      So,the scope in your scenario is about the user instead of client applications you used for user login.
> 2. Not quite clear about your question , could you pls tell me more about your requirement or scenario?
> 3. If you just want to call Microsoft Graph APIs or Office related APIs, server side will check scopes in access token for you. If the access token has no scope that the API required , you will get 403 error with message : "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." There is no need to
>      use it purposely.[This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#using-permissions) has mentioned it too.

Based on your description , what you want to know is : is it possible that get access token with scopes(or permissions) dynamically instead of hard code scopes. It is possible using [Azure AD V2 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)(Each Azure AD Application has v1 and v2 endpoints, v1 just for B2B scenarios and it not supports getting access token with dynamic permissions). And [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent) described your requirement well .

If there is anything unclear or misunderstanding , pls feel free to let me know : )

Comment: Hello , may I know do you have any further concerns about this post ? Is it helpful ?